# python single integer variable between function

Tags: python, list, function, share

Is there a way to exchange between child and parent functions a variable that is not a list?

```
#parent

list=[0]*1
singlevalue = 0

#child - 0
def test():
    list[0]= list[0]+1
    return list

#parent
test() #>>1 
test() #>>2


#child - 1
def test():
    singlevalue = singlevalue +1
    return singlevalue

#parent
test() >>
#    singlevalue = singlevalue +1
#UnboundLocalError: local variable 'singlevalue' referenced before assignment
```

The example show you that with list it output 1 and keep it for next execution.
Why the singlevalue have a different way?

Comment: a) Do not change built-in `list`, use `l`, for example. b) Try to change `list[0]= list[0]+1` to `l = l + [0]` and see, what happens.

Comment: @soon: don't use `l`, use `L`. A lowercase-L letter is quite hard to differentiate from the number 1 in many fonts.

Comment: @6502, I use uppercase for constants. And numbers in my editor are highlighted. In the most, I sure, they are highlighted too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers so far suggest a solution, which was not the point of the post. The difference is that regarding the list, you are working with a reference and are not manipulating a "bound" variable, as you would do with `singlevalue`.
As soon as you would try to do: `l = l + [1]` for example, you would try to modify the bound `l` and get the same error. That is because of how scoping in python work!

**In short**:

```
singlevalue [local variable] = singlevalue [actually a global variable but access to locally stored variable] + 1 [constant]
```

singlevalue is stored locally. Now it wants to access that locally stored variable, which doesn't have a value yet, as it wasn't assigned. IF you want to store it globally you need to use the `global` keyword.

```
list[0] [slot in a referenced list] = list[0] [still same slot, which has a value already]+1
```

Hence, no problem. :)

**In more Detail**:

We can have a look at python's bytecode here and see the difference in loading:

```
>>> def m():
...  y = 1
...  def test():
...   y = y + 1
...   return y
...  test()
>>> m()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
>>> dis.dis(m)
  [... cur here ... Inside of test()]
              # <-- here the value of the constant is loaded from the local namespace
  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object test at 02A067B8, file "<pyshell#33>", line 3>)                   
              9 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (test)
  [... cut here ...]

>>> def l():
...  li = [1]
...  def test():
...   li[0] = li[0] + 1
...   return li
...  test()
>>> l()
[... cut here ... Inside of test()]
              # <-- here a reference is loaded!
  3           9 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (li)
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object test at 02A06698, file "<pyshell#28>", line 3>)
             18 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             21 STORE_FAST               0 (test)
[... cut here ...]
```

As this post would be getting too long I recommend to execute above's commands and have a look here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html to see the difference!

The main difference in how things are stored, however, happens in the first block:

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (y) # <- push loaded constant to stack

  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 BUILD_LIST               1
              6 STORE_DEREF              0 (li) # <- stores the value in the list
```

Have a look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_DEREF)!

I hope this helps clearing the difference. Cheers!

Comment: > This is the point, right? The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when
> the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or
> instances of most classes.

Comment: @user2239318 What do you mean by default value? In case of mutables python is handing around references. So you are at the "right destination" to change something. In case of your integer you are trying to assign to something which is not in the current namespace! `global` adds the variable (reference) to the current namespace!

Answer (score 1):

Would it be helpful to have a look at [defining functions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) on how to pass arguments?

Passing arguments might be more reliable than manipulating a "variable" of which you're hoping it is globally accessible and **mutable**.

Actually, the "variables" are names for references in a (particular) namespace and if you'd check with

```
print id(ll)    # as suggested by others: please don't name your list list ;)
print id(singlevalue)
```

in your functions, you'd see they didn't change. Consequently, you can refer to the name *singlevalue* in any function and print it without any problem.

When trying to change their values, the situation changes:

Lists are mutable objects, you can mess around with them (in any function) without changing their references. Whether it's a better/sexier/more pythonic idea to pass them as arguments is another point.

Strings, however, are immutable. Within you function, you might assign the value of *singlevalue* to another name and boths names will have the same reference. But when you change the value of the new name, it'll have a new reference!

Therefore, i'd suggest to be as lazy as possible but better pass data rather than poking around in the "surrounding" namespace and hope for your best ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global variables. Simply reassign the value of the variable each time.

```
some_variable = 0
def test():
    return some_variable + 1


some_variable = test()  # 1
some_variable = test()  # 2
```

---

Test session on the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> def test():
...     return a + 1
... 
>>> a = test()
>>> a
1
>>> a = test()
>>> a
2
```

Comment: @user2239318 You are *not* doing what I wrote.